# Adjective used to mean "smellable"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms, sense-verbs

An object that can be seen is **visible**.

Something that can be heard is **audible**.

What's a similar word to indicate that something is *smellable*?

Comment: Sniffable? And I'm sure I've seen smellable in at least a few articles now and then.

Comment: Isn't it funny how such words are only regarded as "real" technical terms if they have Latinate (or sometimes Classical Greek) roots?  The Germanic word "smellable" can be found in the dictionary and is instantly understandable, but like "seeable" and "hearable", seems unworthy of being in the company of Latin-based "visible" and "audible".  Objectively speaking, there should be nothing wrong with "smellable". (Note, also, that all the answers so far have suggested Latin-based words as well.)

Comment: But seriously, what’s wrong with the word “smellable”? Why not just use that?

Comment: I think the main problem is that almost all the words we've come up with have either a negative (most) or positive connotation. Interesting, given the role of smelling in survival (is this food bad?) versus seeing and hearing (can you spot the predator/prey?).

Comment: For touch there is [palpable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/palpable) or [tangible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tangible). For taste, it's [tastable.](http://www.wordnik.com/words/tastable)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both *olfactory* and *olfactive* have this meaning, but both words also have the more common meaning of emitting a smell, so they wouldn't be useful.

The best choice would be *olfactible*.  Wiktionary [includes it](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/olfactible), but as far as I can tell, they're the only ones.

Comment: *Olfactible* is a bit of a neologism, but as the geeks inherit the earth (or at least carve out a large subculture of our own) I predict it’ll see more and more use :-P

Comment: Very disappointed that I can't find a Greek word to match. Greek for 'smellable' is *ὀσφραντός*, which doesn't seem to have any descendants in English. *Osphrant* would be my neologism but it's hardly intuitive like *olfactible*. +1 for that.

Answer (score 14):

*[Olfactible](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/olfactible)* (“having an odor; capable of being smelled”) seems relevant.

You may find the [wordnik list](http://www.wordnik.com/lists/odorific) for *odorific* of interest; it includes about five dozen “smelling words”, the first few being  *odoriferous, malodorous, heavenly, redolent, putrid, delectable,  stagnant, fragrant, smelly, noisome, noxious, fetid, aromatic, dank, musty, moldy, fusty*.

Comment: Another for your list: "scented" is very common.

Comment: +1 This seems the only logically correct term among the alternatives presented so far, considering OP's question is about 'capable of being smelled'.

Answer (score 11):

Odorous? <s>(Odourous in the UK)</s> (Same in the UK, see below)

Scented if the smell was added (Strawberry-scented envelopes, but not scented strawberries) or smelly if the smell is pungent or unpleasant (smelly cheese can be good, smelly socks aren't).

Comment: "malodorous" and "fetid" also come to mind for the negative side

Comment: @PSU ooh, good ones.

Comment: No, not "*odourous" in the UK. "Odorous" both in the UK and the US - like "favour" (UK only) but "favorite" (both).

Comment: @psmears: I thought the UK spelling was "favourite". The OED online lists ["favourite"](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0289460#m_en_gb0289460) and shows _favorite_ to be the US spelling.

Comment: @Tragicomic: I'm sorry, you're right about "favourite" of course! I was trying to give an example of one of the pairs where the "u" does disappear in compounds (eg colour/coloration, labour/laborious, rancour/rancorous etc) but picked the wrong one - my apologies!. My comment about UK spelling being "odorous" still stands though :)

Answer (score 8):

An object that can be smelled might be called "fragrant".

Comment: If the smell is pleasant and not too strong. If it's unpleasant or very strong, I'd use *pungent*.

Answer (score 8):

*Smellable* is reported in the NOAD as derivative of *smell*, and I imagine it means *able to be smelled*, in the same way *calculable* means "able to be measured or assessed."

Comment: I was referring to _calculable_, but I have written _calculate_ by mistake. I was making a comparison between _smellable_ and another word ending in _-able_; clearly the paragon cannot be done with _calculate_, which doesn't end in _-able_.

Answer (score 8):

English syntax allows us to stick *smell* and *able* together.

Something gives off an odor (or perhaps doesn't) but for some reason, we cannot detect it. Perhaps it is too far!

*I see a flower in a yard across the street, but it isn't smellable from here, though it is undoubtedly odorous, odoriferous, fragrant, and smelly. It can be smelled, just not in this situation.*

Comment: FWIW: NOAD lists _smellable_ as an adjective, under its entry for _smell_. OED gives _smellable_ its own entry, with the definition, "Capable of being smelt."

Answer (score 5):

The word you want is *[odoriferous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/odoriferous)* (sometimes shortened to *odiferous*): "Having an odour or fragrance."

A synonym given on the Wiktionary link is *odorous.*

Comment: None of them means smell-able.

Answer (score 4):

**Aromatic** is another word for this:

From Merriam-Webster:

1 : of, relating to, or having aroma:
a : fragrant
b : having a strong smell

Comment: Probably the best answer, imo. *Aromatic* doesn't imply anything about the qualities of the aroma in question, unlike "odorous" or "fragrant", despite that latter being the 2nd definition. *Aromatic* is the closest I can think of to "having a smell".

Answer (score 3):

"Odiferous", which seems to be a contraction of "odoriferous" means "yielding an odor" per Merriam Webster ([odoriferous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/odoriferous))

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps *[odoriferous](http://www.yourdictionary.com/odoriferous), [odiferous](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/odiferous), [odorous](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/odorous), or [fragrant](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/fragrance)*.

And there is always *[smelly](http://www.yourdictionary.com/smelly)*.

Comment: The first four do mean *smelly*. None of them means smell-able.

Comment: @Kris: So, you're saying that **smell : odiferous :: hearing : loud**; however, the O.P. is asking for **[something] : smell :: audible : hearing**.

Comment: @J.R. The question is clear enough. Let's wait for OP's response.

Comment: @Kris: I was just trying to make sure I understood your objections to the first two answers. It took me a moment to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Odorable. (Not to be confused with 'adorable')

Meaning 'Able to be smelled. Perceptible to the sense of smell'.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/odorable

Answer (score 0):

The word **chemosensory** seems to fit what's being asked for.

Comment: And I'm sure everyone's going to know exactly what's meant by it!