# Word for "able to be smelled"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adjective used to mean “smellable”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12549/adjective-used-to-mean-smellable)

What's the word for "able to be smelled"? *Audible* is for sounds, and *visible* for sights. Is there an equivalent word for smells? *Smellable* sounds wrong. (Related: what about taste and touch?)

Comment: @Kris, yes, this appears to be a duplicate and may need to merge with older question